# Typescript type-safe event listener

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, eventemitter, typesafe

So, I got this pseudo-code for a EventListener just for trying out the types and etc, but I didn't manage to find a way to make typescript change `payload` parameter into a specific type depending on `event` parameter value.

```js
type READY = {
  A: boolean;
};

type CONNECTING = {
  B: boolean;
};

type DispatcherPayloads = {
  READY: READY;
  CONNECTING: CONNECTING;
};

type DispatcherEvents = keyof DispatcherPayloads;

type EmitterEventsListeners = {
  dispatch: <DispatcherEvent extends DispatcherEvents>(
    event: DispatcherEvent,
    payload: DispatcherPayloads[DispatcherEvent]
  ) => void;
};

type EmitterEventsNames = keyof EmitterEventsListeners;

function on<EmitterEventName extends EmitterEventsNames>(
  event: EmitterEventName,
  listener: EmitterEventsListeners[EmitterEventName]
) {
  listener("READY", { A: true })
}

on("dispatch", (event, payload) => {
  if(event === "READY") {
    console.log(payload.A) // COMPILER GIVES ERROR
    /**
      Property 'A' does not exist on type 'READY | CONNECTING'.
      Property 'A' does not exist on type 'CONNECTING'.(2339)
    **/
  }
})
```

I tried everything on my knowledge but it seems impossible. Would I need to do it in alternative way? I thought of some but I preferred sticking into this one but it seems not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `event` and `payload` are generic types and there is currently no way for the compiler to narrow the type of `payload` by checking the value of `event`.

We can solve this by using discrimanted unions. By using a mapped type, we can construct a union of all valid `event` and `payload` combinations. The resulting tuple union can be properly discriminated by the compiler based on the `event` type.

You need to modify `EmitterEventsListeners` to look like this:

```
type EmitterEventsListeners = {
  dispatch: (
    ...args: { 
        [K in keyof DispatcherPayloads]: [event: K, payload: DispatcherPayloads[K]] 
    }[keyof DispatcherPayloads]
  ) => void;
};
```

The resulting type of `...args` is now

```
args: 
 | [event: "READY", payload: READY] 
 | [event: "CONNECTING", payload: CONNECTING]
```

which solves the narrowing issue.

```
on("dispatch", (event, payload) => {
  if(event === "READY") {
    console.log(payload.A)
  } else if (event === "CONNECTING") {
    console.log(payload.B)
  }
})
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=39&ssc=3&pln=33&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBASgogQQCIE0oF4oG8BQUoIBcUARgPZkA2EAhgHYDcOAvkzqJFAMIDyAcnzhcAKgEk+AcQzY8UAELFyVWoxZsO0JAEsAzmBrAAxgAsIAJwAKNEJTI0AJjum588ZCmJvUTfLwFCxSWI-QRFxCSZWHHZwTV19I1MzOAA3CDpgJ0wAawgQMgAzKG09AxNzKxs7R3VYqDgAWy1gYHNU9MyAGV1WunMsmXx7eLLjYgAKWXwAOlmaMwBzHWIsKCn8DYBtAGkoLTooXPyikoTyy2tbBx0AXWJNiDSM4m2AGih9KodiU9GKy+qOh2Nxuaw2UGYmyOhWKI0S-y+jhusgAlBgAHxQFJkLT2SK1TiNZqtZJPTJ8GgNCADaFFIktNpknTdHS9fpsAoAVzohmAWjIBwFAB56ST2hkKVSoBAAB69Rz1JoM0kdHSS6noyb4R4dYiixkddWvWSUHrpcx6pVipkstlmIH6lUSykQZFolxQU2s81mcYAIi8KD971WRCgwDMnOgzBRLGiAv9w1KiWDUHGOoy70+V3saPQmI9WgK6bJGHQmADiFQfvd60MAp0ymmtgW42z1WmCFj+GY0soOmgRbTGeAZYrIQC4Rrgw29bojeozbIrfbDmmcm7EJYKKAA)